# Stringstream won't output additional variables?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have this program that reads integers entered by a user. The program first reads the input as a string and then I use string stream convert it to an integer. The problem is that the string stream only outputs the first input. So after the first input userNumInput remains as the first input because it doesn't read anything else.

```
    stringstream so;
    string userInput;
    int userNumInput = 0;

    while(userInput != "done") {
        cout << "Enter an integer or type done: ";
        cin >> userInput;
        if (isdigit(userInput[0])){
            so << userInput; //here is the problem
            so >> userNumInput; 
            userVector.push_back(userNumInput);
            so.str("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You seem to be very confused what these statements do in particular. Once input was read from a stream, cou can't consume it again unless manipulating the stream state.

Comment: Yeah I just learned string stream like two days ago. That makes sense though.

Comment: @Chillax23 instead of using same stringstream instance via clearing it, just declare it in while loop. Moreover, you can read inputs as integers as well which will eliminate conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> userVector;
stringstream so;
string userInput;
int userNumInput = 0;

while (userInput != "done") {
    cout << "Enter an integer or type done: ";
    cin >> userInput;
    if (isdigit(userInput[0])) {
        so << userInput; //here is the problem
        so >> userNumInput;
        userVector.push_back(userNumInput);
        so.str("");
    }
    so.clear(); //here is the solution
}
for (int i = 0; i < userVector.size(); i++)
    cout << userVector[i] << endl;
```